# What number you deleted with backspace

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

When I delete a number in a textbox with backspace I want to save that number so that I can compare it with other numbers in my other textboxes. How do I do that?
This is the code where I want to put it in:

```
List<TextBox> box1;
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {   box1 = this.Controls.OfType<TextBox>()
              .Where(x => x.Name.StartsWith("textBox1")).ToList();

        foreach (TextBox t in box1)
            t.TextChanged += textBox_TC1;
     }

private void textBox_TC1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox textBox = (TextBox)sender;
        if (textBox.Text.Length == 1 && allwhite == 0)
        {
            bool sameText = box1.Any(x => x.Text == textBox.Text &&
                                         !x.Equals(textBox));

            if (sameText)
                textBox.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;

        }
        else if (textBox.Text.Length == 0)
        {
            textBox.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
        }
    }
```

I want to put my new code in 'else if (textBox.Text.Length == 0)' because I can only delete text with backspace in my textboxes and the maxlength is 1. 
When I backspace something I want to compare that number to all the other textboxes in box1 and then if that number is equal to only one other textbox, it'll make that other textbox backcolor white. I have no idea how to save a number that's about to be deleted so if you could help me I'll be so happy.

Comment: You can store previous value (as a field), when `TextChanged` is rised you can take previous value, check if it has one number less, etc. Or you can use another event (e.g. `KeyDown`) to detect the moment when Backspace is pressed.

Comment: are you trying to compare passwords or something?

Comment: You should use `TextChanged` event, and at the end of `TextChanged` you should keep current value somewhere like `Tag` property of your `TextBox` and use it when you want to compare it with other values. You should not use any event other than `TextChanged` because the user can delete or paste values without useing keyboard.

Comment: @Sinatr I don't only have 1 textbox, I have 81 that are in lists, so if I'm going to store numbers for specific textboxes I need something that can check what lists these textboxes are in because all my textboxes are in 2 different lists and I have 18 lists. And that I have no idea how to do.

Comment: @FarhanAnam I'm making a sudoku

Comment: You should have mentioned it in your post. Because it's a sudoku, there's only one number in each box, i guess?

Comment: @FarhanAnam **my textboxes and the maxlength is 1**

Comment: Have you found out the comparing logic? If so, then you can use `TextBox1.TextChanged` Event to monitor the textbox. The event will fire whenever the text is changed regardless of whether by keyboard or even by code (if that's the case).

Comment: @RezaAghaei Oh i missed that point. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `TextChanged` event to detect changes on your `TextBox`, and at the end of `TextChanged` you should keep current value somewhere like `Tag` property of your `TextBox` and use it when you want to compare it with other values. You should not use any event other than `TextChanged` because the user can delete or paste values without useing keyboard.

For example you can write code like this:

```
...
else if (textBox.Text.Length == 0)
{
    var previusText = textBox.Tag as string;
    var items= box1.Where(x => x.Text == previusText && !x.Equals(textBox)).ToList();
    if (items.Count()==1)
    {
        items[0].BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
    }
}

//Keep previous text
textBox.Tag = textBox.Text;
...
```

Comment: This code only makes the box that was changed to white, not the one that is equal to it. And I've already fixed that you can't delete or paste values without keyboard or with ctrl+a or ctrl+z so you don't have to worry about that.

Comment: @Percutient this is main idea and you can change it to your will:) I don't read all of your codes. As I see, you know how to use linq to find controls well, so simply change the code and bend it to your will.

Comment: @Percutient but you get the main idea that is using `TextChanged` event and keeping previous value in `Tag`.

Comment: @Percutient And you can now check the edited answer :)

Comment: I understand that your code is trying to put the previous text into textBox.Tag. But when you put 'x.Text == previusText', x.text is already empty, so previusText is also an empty string because all this happens when textBox.Text.Length is 0. Atleast that's how it looks to me and I can't think of any way to fix that.

Comment: @Percutient `x.text` is text of other `TextBox` and is not empty, also we cached it in `Tag` after the job get done, so the `Tag` really contains **Deleted value**. I think the post answers your main question  **What number you deleted with backspace** and I have no idea about the logic behind the application. I think now you can write your logic based on the idea. I did my best to help you :)

Comment: @Percutient Making decision about accepting/not accepting answers is completely your right :)

Comment: Just want to say thank you. It might sound like I'm complaining but it's just that I don't get it. But if tag has the deleted value I can somehow make it work. Thank you once again.

Comment: @Percutient You are welcome and thank you for your feedback. Let me know if you need more help.

Comment: @Percutient  pay attention `textBox.Tag = textBox.Text;`  executes after your search. so in search we have not updated `Tag` yet, and so `Tag` contains a value from previous `TextChanged` event. hope it helps you to overcome the problem:)

Answer (score 1):

You could use this approach:

```
static void textBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    TextBox t = sender as TextBox;
    switch (e.KeyCode)
    {
        case Keys.Delete:
        case Keys.Back:
            int start = e.KeyCode == Keys.Back && t.SelectionLength == 0 ? t.SelectionStart - 1 : t.SelectionStart;
            int length = t.SelectionLength == 0 ? 1 : t.SelectionLength;

            // you can save your char right here....!

            t.Text = t.Text.Remove(start, length);

            e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe user doesn't use backspace or delete to delete the character and only select the text and type/paste a new character. The solution must handle all cases.